# Problema para recuperar respuesta en consulta SOAP

Tags: php, soap

Me dirijo a vosotros porque tengo un problema a la hora de recuperar el `stdClass Object` que me devuelve mi consulta SOAP.

La pregunta del millón, ¿cómo coger esos datos que me devuelve y meterlos en `input` de un formulario?

```
<?php
# Para evitar configurar directamente el archivo de configuración de PHP
# Podemos realizarlo directamente en el codigo,
# deshabilitaremos el cache de los wsdl para soap.
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

# Especificamos el wsdl que utilizaremos en nuestro servicio web.
$wsdl = 'https://webserviceprueba.com/consulta?WSDL';
# Instanciamos un cliente nativo de la clase de PHP con el $wsdl especificado anteriormente.
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

# El cliente tiene varias funciones para obtener información, una de esas es:
# __getFunctions() la cual nos listara todas las acciones soap que contiene un servicio web.
// var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
# Realizamos la llamada al servicio web con __soapCall
# Donde el primer parametro es la accion que llamara, y el segundo los parametros esperados por el web service
$consulta = $client->__soapCall("mifuncion", array(
    "USUARI" => "miusario",
    "CLAU" => "micontraseña" ,
    "COR" => "18" ,
    "CUP" => "07240" ,
    "CIP" => "GOFE4242525201",
    "DREF" => "?"));

print_r($consulta);
```

Hasta hay todo esta bien. Pero mi interés es coger los datos que me da cuando ejecuto `print_r($consulta);` e introducirlos cada uno en su `input` correspondiente.

El resultado de `print_r($consulta);` es el siguiente:

```
stdClass Object ( [APLICACIO] => RCAXML [OPCIO] => CONSULTA_CIP [TIMESTAMP_INICIAL] => Fri Sep 06 17:58:18 CEST 2019 [TIMESTAMP_FINAL] => Fri Sep 06 17:58:18 CEST 2019 [CODI_RESULTAT_GCX] => 0000 [DESCRIPCIO_RESULTAT_GCX] => OK [CODI_RESULTAT_CLIENT] => 0000 [USUARI] => ep0093ws [MISSATGE] => stdClass Object ( [DFC] => stdClass Object ( [REGISTRE] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [DFC_ACE] => [DFC_ALO] => [DFC_ANT] => [DFC_AOFT] => 200601 [DFC_CABS] => 310 [DFC_CAD] => [DFC_CAP] => RCA [DFC_CAP_O] => [DFC_CAUP] => T [DFC_CBL] => [DFC_CCC_A] => 2 [DFC_CCC_CIP] => 0 [DFC_CCC_I] => 1 [DFC_CCC_L] => 1 [DFC_CCC_T] => 0 [DFC_CCP] => 1 [DFC_CDE_1] => [DFC_CDE_2] => [DFC_CDINE] => 1 [DFC_CDP] => 08755 [DFC_CEC] => 02 [DFC_CES] => [DFC_CFO_PC] => XL [DFC_CFO_SC] => FN [DFC_CGGC] => 0003 [DFC_CIDI] => C [DFC_CIP] => GOFE1320104001 [DFC_CIP_V] => GOFE1320104001 [DFC_CLO] => 0805400 [DFC_CMCT] => [DFC_CMRTS] => [DFC_CNSQ] => [DFC_COR] => 07240 [DFC_COR_1] => 18 [DFC_CPO] => [DFC_COR_2] => [DFC_COT] => [DFC_CPA] => [DFC_CPASS] => [DFC_CPE] => [DFC_CPIS] => [DFC_CTO] => 18 [DFC_CMO] => CA [DFC_CPOR] => [DFC_CRAA] => 0001 [DFC_CSA] => A [DFC_CSINE] => 5 [DFC_CSTSI] => A [DFC_CTP] => [DFC_CUG] => [DFC_CUP] => 00355 [DFC_CUP_S] => [DFC_CUP_T] => 00355 [DFC_CUS_C] => [DFC_DAL] => [DFC_DAL_A] => [DFC_DCF] => [DFC_DCF_A] => [DFC_DDID] => 23/11/2010 [LAS_TVI] => [LAS_NVIA_I] => [LAS_NVIA_F] => [LAS_NVI] => [LAS_NQU] => [DFC_DIDP_A] => [DFC_DIDP] => [DFC_DDTSI] => 27/01/2006 [DFC_DDTSI_A] => [DFC_DDL] => 23/11/2010 [DFC_DDL_A] => [DFC_DFDP] => [DFC_DFDP_A] => [DFC_DIP] => [DFC_DNA] => 04/01/1932 [DFC_DNA_A] => [DFC_ERR] => [DFC_IBIS] => N [DFC_ICIPM] => N [DFC_IDA] => [DFC_IDI] => [DFC_IDL] => [DFC_IDM] => [DFC_IDT] => [DFC_IIEC] => N [DFC_IIT] => [DFC_ILTU] => [DFC_IPAD] => N [DFC_ITRE] => N [DFC_LSE] => [DFC_MEC] => /02 [DFC_NAAS] => 080140669022 [DFC_NART_SOL] => [DFC_NCP] => 0 [DFC_NDID] => 38517652N [DFC_NFI] => CONSULTA.TXT [DFC_NIA] => 2750672 [DFC_NLO] => CASTELLBISBAL [DFC_NLT] => [DFC_NOGT] => 4 [DFC_NPE] => BLANCA [DFC_NQU] => [DFC_NRD] => 1 [DFC_NRD_IDA] => [DFC_NRD_TDL] => [DFC_NVIA_F] => [DFC_NRE] => [DFC_NSAPA] => [DFC_NSQ] => 117099896 [DFC_NTE_1] => 7720066 [DFC_NTE_2] => 7722416 [DFC_NVI] => PALMERA [DFC_NVIA_I] => 43 [DFC_PCG] => GONZALEZ [DFC_PRO] => P [DFC_RAEC] => B [DFC_SCG] => FERNANDEZ [DFC_SEXE] => 1 [DFC_TAA] => PN [DFC_TDI] => 1 [DFC_TDL] => [DFC_TFX] => 9 [DFC_TOR] => 18 [DFC_TRE] => 99 [DFC_TVI] => CR [LAS_CBL] => [LAS_CDP] => [LAS_CES] => [LAS_CLO] => [LAS_CPIS] => [LAS_CPO] => [LAS_CPOR] => [LAS_DDL] => [LAS_DDL_A] => [LAS_IBIS] => [LAS_NLO] => [DFC_CTT] => 4 [DFC_DCP] => COB. SANITÀRIA GENERAL FARM. GRAT. [DFC_DDA] => 23/11/2010 [DFC_DDA_A] => [DFC_DDID_A] => ) ) ) [ERRORS] => ) )
```

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos a continuación (en tu pregunta) cómo se ve el resultado de `print_r($consulta);` y tu código HTML donde tienes los `input`? No tienes por qué usar datos reales, puedes cambiarlos por otros del mismo tipo.

Comment: @Roxgüel SI MI RESPUESTA SE VE DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA

Comment: @Roxgüel Acabo de editarla la pregunta y añadido la respuesta que me  sale

Comment: @Roxgüel los inputs los tengo en la misma pagina

Comment: @Roxgüel Alguna Idea de como puedo Hacerlo ?????

Comment: Si accedes de la forma $consulta->APLICACIO que sucede ?

Comment: @Anibal Ospina Me da error de sintaxi

Comment: @AnibalOspina gRACIAS ERES UN CRACK ME FUNCIONO ;)

Comment: @AnibalOspina ME DA EL SIGUIENTE ERROR Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$CIP in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEB SERVICE RCA\send-peticio-soap-rca.php on line 31

Comment: @AnibalOspina  tienes alguna iadea de como puedo pasar el stdclass a un array ?

Comment: A que informacion quieres acceder ?

Comment: @AnibalOspina intento acceder a los datos arrojados tras una consulta soap a un web service